# Recommendation for Chart Label with 2 Actions

Tags: ux-designer, product-design

I'm currently designing an app and I have a label that should have two actions: 1. Right Click (1st Action) opens a popover with more details on the part (Gear Box) like the number of parts that make up the Gear Box. Right click (2nd action) drills down deeper into the part (Parts that make up the Gearbox). From a UX perspective, is this the best approach or is there a better solution? I'm not sure how to best solve this problem. Thanks   [image: Screenshot of button]

Comment: Just to clarify, do you use the right-click for both actions?

Comment: Can you describe the situation in more detail, perhaps with some (more) images and some background information? It is a bit unclear what you try to achieve and why.